# How do I migrate my code from .Net Framework to .Net Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, .net-core, migration

I am trying to migrate my project from EF to .Net Core with wpf. Now, I installed the EntityFrameworkCore 3.1 but it doesn't support ObjectSet, MergeOption, RefreshMode and ObjectContext, all EF functions. 
How would my code look if I implemented it in .Net core?

This's my CommonDbContext.cs in Entity Framework:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Data.Objects;
using System.Linq;

namespace Infrastructure.Data.SQL
{
    public class CommonDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public CommonDbContext(string name)
            : base(name)
        {
        }

        public IQueryable<T> ReadOnly<T>() where T : class
        {
            ObjectSet<T> result = ObjContext().CreateObjectSet<T>();
            result.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
            return result;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Trackable<T>() where T : class
        {
            return ObjContext().CreateObjectSet<T>();
        }

        public void Refresh(IEnumerable collection)
        {
            ObjContext().Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, collection);
        }

        public void Refresh(object item)
        {
            ObjContext().Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, item);
        }

        public void Detach(object item)
        {
            ObjContext().Detach(item);
        }

        public void LoadProperty(object item, string propertyName)
        {
            ObjContext().LoadProperty(item, propertyName);
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            ObjContext().Connection.Close();
        }

        public ObjectContext ObjContext()
        {
            return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        }

        public void AcceptAllChanges()
        {
            ObjContext().AcceptAllChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start porting your code to EF Core as described in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/).

Comment: No, upgrade to EF 6.4, which supports .Net core. Apart from that, it would be a good idea to get `ObjectContext` out of the picture completely.

Comment: @GertArnold: EF6 is no longer being actively developed so if you are serious about upgrading your apps to .NET Core and currently use EF, you should definitely consider upgrading to EF Core as well.

Comment: It is true that EF is no longer actively developing; therefore, I have made the decision to move my application completely to net core, but I am a bit lost as I am newbie to this

Comment: Sure, EF6 is not the focus version of the EF team, but it allows porting an application to .net core without a big bang scenario. My personal road map in OP's code would be: 1. remove any reference to the `ObjectContext` API, 2. upgrade to EF 6.4, still in .net framework, 3. port to .net core. with the least possible amount of code changes, 4. port to EF 3 core. Each of these steps will probably have easily deductible regression, step 3 probably being the hardest of all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a partial port of that to EF Core 3.  But some things just work differently, and you'll need to adapt other parts of the code.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;


namespace Infrastructure.Data.SQL
{
    public class CommonDbContext : DbContext
    {

        public IQueryable<T> ReadOnly<T>() where T : class
        {
            return Set<T>().AsNoTracking();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Trackable<T>() where T : class
        {
            return Set<T>();
        }

        public void Refresh(IEnumerable collection)
        {
            foreach(var e in collection)
            {
                Refresh(e);
            }
        }

        public void Refresh(object item)
        {
            Entry(item).Reload();
        }

        public void Detach(object item)
        {
            Entry(item).State = EntityState.Detached;
        }

        public void LoadProperty(object item, string propertyName)
        {
            Entry(item).Reference(propertyName).Load();
        }

        public void Close()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        //public ObjectContext ObjContext()
        //{
        //    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        //}

        public void AcceptAllChanges()
        {
            ChangeTracker.AcceptAllChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Browne Thanks for your help... Why is the ObjectContext function excluded?

Comment: Because there is no ObjectContext in EF Core.